# Good tools for monitoring my existing hadoop eco-system?

Tags: hadoop, system, ambari

I am looking for a very good tools or open-source system to monitor my hadoop eco-system inluding components like hadoop,spark,oozie,yarn,hdfs,hive,hbase,kafka,zookeeper and so on.

I get ambari but I find that current ambari can be just used to deploy and manage my system from scratch, instead of managing my existing hadoop system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can Try Ankush(Open Source) from Impetus https://github.com/impetus-opensource/ankush/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Ambari has very decent monitoring/alerting capabilities and allow to monitor all the Hadoop components. Check Ambari user guide ([see one for the most recent version in PDF](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.2.0/bk_ambari-user-guide/bk_ambari-user-guide-20161128.pdf)). Specifically, see Section 2 (Ambari Dashboards) and Section 8 (Monitoring and Alerts).

p.s. There is a promising project in this space (but still currently at the incubating phase), called [Apache Eagle](https://github.com/apache/eagle). It attempts to go beyond monitoring itself, particularly to help with identifying different sorts of issues with a Hadoop cluster.